# Groupings in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a tables that contains the below values.

```
region      state
---------   ----------
region01    state01
region01    state02
region02    state03
```

On the above data, I want to get all the regions in just single row that's why I've to used the GROUP_CONCAT. But it seems that my below query duplicates the `region01` and having a result of

```
region01;region01;region02
```

Can any one help me on how to improve the below query so that the return value should not duplicates the same data

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(region SEPARATOR ';') AS region
  FROM table1
 WHERE field1='BUSINESS01';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT region SEPARATOR ';') AS region
FROM table1
WHERE field1='BUSINESS01';
```

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

> DISTINCT specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set.

Answer (score 1):

u have to use this syntax

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT region SEPARATOR ';') AS region
  FROM table1
 WHERE field1='BUSINESS01';
```

its give u only unique field values